# Combining two plots with `fplot`

Tags: matlab, plot

Consider

```
x_1 = @(A,t,C_prey)C_prey*exp(t*A)
```

and

```
x_2 = @(B,t,C_prey,C_predator)C_prey*exp(t*(-B*C_predator))
```

For a start:

```
fplot(x_1([0.01 0.05 0.08],t,1),[0,0.1])
```

and

```
fplot(x_2([0.01 0.05 0.08],t,1,1),[0,0.1])
```

But when I attempt to plot them both together

```
fplot(x_1([0.01 0.05 0.08],t,1),x_2([0.01 0.05 0.08],t,1,1))
```

I am prompted by MATLAB with `Error updating ParameterizedFunctionLine.`

It doesn't seem as though my syntax is wrong since MATLAB documentation gave an example of plotting two functions with fplot in a rather straight forward manner.

What is wrong here?

Comment: This is not a valid statement. `fplot(x_1([0.01 0.05 0.08],t,1),[0,0.1])` Why don't you use simply use `hold on` just like in the [*documentation*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fplot.html#bu6xntl-13). And don't delete your questions only to ask them again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you planning to plot 2 functions in general form or 1 function in parametric form? In the former case, like @SardarUsama said, you have to fix the syntax use `hold on`. Such as:

```
x_1 = @(A,t,C_prey)C_prey*exp(t*A);
x_2 = @(B,t,C_prey,C_predator)C_prey*exp(t*(-B*C_predator));

fplot(@(t)x_1([0.01 0.05 0.08],t,1), [0,0.1]); 
hold on; 
fplot(@(t)x_2([0.01 0.05 0.08],t,1,1), [0,0.1]); 
grid on; hold off;
```

Here, for each value in `A(or B):[0.01 0.05 0.08]`, you will get 2 curves (x_1 and x_2). However, if you want to plot only one function in parametric form then you have to plot one curve for each value of `A`. Such as:

```
A = [0.01 0.05 0.08];
figure; grid on; hold on;
for i=1:length(A)
    fplot(@(t)x_1(A(i),t,1),@(t)x_2(A(i),t,1,1), [0,0.1]);
end
```